# Azure Reporting

Tags: windows, azure, reporting

I have Main SSRS report with few drill down reports calling same main report with parameters. It works fine in Regular SSRS. When I upload the same report on Azure the main report works fine without problem. When I click on the drill down links it keeps on giving error saying `The Item "reportname" cannot be found. Tracing id is : (rsItemNotFound)`. What change I need to make in the SSRS to have the drill down report work in Azure environment.

Answer (score 2):

There shouldn't be a need to change anything between between regular SSRS and Azure Reporting.

I had a simular problem once. In my case it happened since I renamed the report at one point, but the drill down action was still using the old report name. Maybe you have a simular problem?

Also, check out the Azure Reporting limitations [over here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg430132.aspx) (in case your report happens to use an unsupported feature like RDCE)